# Meaning of $\big|_{t=0}$ beside a derivative in a theorem about the properties of the characteristic function of a random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

What does the $\big|_{t=0}$ mean in this context?

Comment: It is the point at which the derivative is taken.

Comment: So it is the same as $\frac{d^{k}}{dt^{k}}\varphi_{X}(0)$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: What text is this from?

Comment: Introduction to Probability and Stochastic Processes with Applications by Dharmaraja Selvamuthu, Liliana Blanco Castaneda, and Viswanathan Arunachalam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol is not something unique to probability. An equivalent statement would be, say,

$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} \Bigg|_{x = x_0} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} f'(x_0) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f(x_0)$$

or similarly

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^kf}{\mathrm{d}x^k} \Bigg|_{x = x_0}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} f^{(k)}(x_0) = \frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k} f(x_0)$$

as another example. You can also think of it as analogous to a notation for antiderivatives:

$$\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = F(x) \bigg|_{x=a}^{x=b} = F(b) - F(a)$$

In short, it represents an evaluation of some sort.

Comment: This is correct; I'll just remark that the notation is IMO most useful when the function is not given a symbol for a name. E.g. $\frac{\text d}{\text dx} x^2 |_{x=1} = 2$